# Contact form not working on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, templates, contact-form

I am following [this tutorial](http://boxmodeljunkie.com/create-a-simple-php-contact-form/).

I made a `Contact.php` template to customize this page. I copied and pasted everything that was needed.

I uploaded my `validate.php` file to my themes file folder

```
public_html/test/wp-content/themes/themename
```

I have static pages, my **main** page is the front page while **news** is my posts page.

Every time I submit the form I get redirected to the **news** page but the URL says `domain.com/test/` instead of `domain.com/test/contact` (where the form is obviously located).

For my `contact.php` template I just added the code I needed to the very top, underneath the `template tag` and above the `get_header tag`.

Here are pastes bins for my PHP pages:

**[CONTACT.PHP (Template)](http://pastebin.com/J4piD1s7)**

**[VALIDATE.PHP](http://pastebin.com/bmnD1zSs)**

Comment: It's good you try and make your own contact form, but using a CMS there are plenty of plugins that save you the time and hassle ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress, why make it hard on yourself? Use Contact Form 7, easy as hell to configure, provides good validation and is broadly used contact form.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: It messes up my whole footer. And the way it's style is ugly to me... I'd like to learn this way for when I'm not using WordPress...

Comment: Managed to fix my footer, but I still don't know how to style the form.

Comment: Lol so my CSS can overwrite the plugins default CSS? I never knew how to do that. I tried this plugin before and deleted it due to the ugly result. I'm sure when I'm not using WordPress for a design I'll be posting the same question without WordPress in the title. lol.

Comment: @keihead, idk whether it's the plugin or style.css of your theme (most ,likely plugin) but it all comes down to basic css to style it ...

Comment: I have a question about this plugin...after the form is successfully sent in, This "#wpcf7-f443-p133-o1" gets added to the url..now THAT is uglier than the form it's self. :( Any way at all to remove that?

Comment: @keihead, follow the instructions on how to properly configure it :) my contactform (using this plugin) doesn't add anything to the url.